# ggplot - retaining axis label coloring with reordered data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a horizontal bar chart where each observation has a numeric count variable associated with it. I want to show the bars for each variable ordered by (descending) count, which is no problem. However I also want to highlight the variable name based on a third dichotomous variable. I found how to do the latter in another post on here, but I have been unable to combine the two. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
library(ggplot2)

testdata<-data.frame("var"=c('V1','V2','V3','V4'),"cat"=c('Y','N','Y','N'),
"count"=c(1,5,2,10))

ggplot(testdata, aes(var,count))+
geom_bar(stat='identity',colour='blue',fill='blue',width=0.3)+ 
coord_flip(ylim=c(0,10))+
theme(axis.text.y=
element_text(colour=ifelse(testdata$cat=="N","darkgreen","darkred"),
size=15))
```

That's the horizontal bar chart with highlighting, which works fine - V1/V3 are red and V2/V4 are green.

However when I try to sort it doesn't keep the groups:

```
ggplot(testdata, aes(reorder(var,count),count))+
geom_bar(stat='identity',colour='blue',fill='blue',width=0.3)+ 
coord_flip(ylim=c(0,10))+theme_classic()+
theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
theme(axis.text.y=
element_text(colour=ifelse(testdata$cat=="N","darkgreen","darkred"),
size=15))
```

In this second graph, V2 and V3 are the wrong color.

I also tried sorting the data by count first, and then using the first ggplot statement, however it still plots the data by variable name instead of count (and even if it did work, I would have to resolve tied count values). Any ideas? What I really need is for the dataframe in the "ifelse" colour to match the dataframe in the aes statement. I tried using the data frame that was sorted by descending count in the colour statement, but that also did not work.

Thanks

edit: more code

```
testdata$var = with(testdata, reorder(var, count))

ggplot(testdata, aes(var,count))+
geom_bar(stat='identity',colour='blue',fill='blue',width=0.3)+ 
coord_flip(ylim=c(0,10))+theme_classic()+
theme(axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
theme(axis.text.y=
element_text(colour=ifelse(testdata$cat=="N","darkgreen","darkred"),
size=15))
```

Comment: Do your data modification (the `reorder` part) before the plot and save it in the data, `testdata$var = with(testdata, reorder(var, count))`. Essentially, you're modifying the data on the fly in `ggplot`, but the `theme` bit doesn't have access to the modified data and it is just using the original data. You solve the problem by saving the modification in the original data. I assume by "sorting the data" you mean changing the order of the rows - that does nothing. The only thing that matters for the order of the axis is the order of the factor levels, `levels(testdata$var)`.

Comment: I added some new code based on what you said, however the colors are still wrong. V4/V3 are green, V2/V1 are red in the new plot. It looks like the colours are correct, however the levels of "cat" are not. They are still YNYN as they are in the original data before the reordering.

Comment: thanks that works!!! I'm still (relatively) new to R so I really don't understand the use of the equal sign as opposed to "<-"

Comment: `=` vs `<-` is a style thing. I like `=` better, so that's what I use. Nothing more to it than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment was partially incorrect. The order of the levels is the only thing that matters for the order of the axis, **but** when we do `ifelse(testdata$cat == "N", "darkgreen", "darkred")` of course it goes in the order of the data! So we need the order of the levels and the order of the data to be the same:

```
testdata$var = with(testdata, reorder(var, count))
testdata = testdata[order(testdata$var), ]

ggplot(testdata, aes(var, count)) +
    geom_bar(
        stat = 'identity',
        colour = 'blue',
        fill = 'blue',
        width = 0.3
    ) +
    coord_flip(ylim = c(0, 10)) + theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.ticks.y = element_blank()) +
    theme(axis.text.y =
                    element_text(
                        colour = ifelse(testdata$cat == "N", "darkgreen", "darkred"),
                        size = 15
                    ))
```

[image]